# Animation bound KeyTime not working

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, data-binding

I'm currently trying to make a `TextBlock` fade in and out when it's `Text` property changes. I have this XAML:

```
<TextBlock DataContext="{Binding ElementName=main, Path=DataContext}"
           Height="18"
           Text="{Binding CurrentStatus, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}">
  <TextBlock.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated">
      <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
          <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0:1" Value="1"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="{Binding AnimationTime}" Value="1"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0:1" Value="0"/>
          </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
  </TextBlock.Triggers>
</TextBlock>
```

What I would except from this is: First, take 1 second to fade in, then stay at `Opacity` 1 for the duration of `AnimationTime` and then take 1 second to fade out. I have checked the value of `AnimationTime` with Snoop, and the value is fine. But the animation seems to ignore the bound value and the fade out also doesnt work. So now, it fades in like expected but then is instantly gone. The Text is also still there. Does anyone see anything wrong with that code?

EDIT: `AnimationTime` is a `TimeSpan` btw

Comment: `<EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0:1" Value="0"/>` this is the last keyframe, it has the keytime exactly as the second keyframe. Is this a typo? I think that keyframe will force the Opacity to `0` right when it goes to nearly `1` (so the fading-out does not work).

Comment: So the last keyFrame needs to be the time AnimatioNTime took PLUS the fade out time?

Comment: it should be so, just try it yourself. You can even remove the Binding (set some direct value) to see in it action first.

Comment: ah yes, that seems to be the problem. If you post an answer, Ill gladly accept it. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad it helped but I would not add the answer, as you see it's a bit trivial.

Comment: Well in this case I just misunderstood how the KeyTimes or rather the DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames worked. I think it will be useful for others! :)